# How to move a character by pressing a button?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I am new in Unity. Right now I am in deep trouble. I have a character in unity. I can move it through keyboard. Now I want to move that character(like: run,walk,jump) by using buttons. How can I move that character by using buttons? Please help me.....

Comment: What do you mean by 'buttons'? Mouse buttons? Gamepad buttons? Using the mouse to click on a UI button element on screen?

Answer (score 3):

If your game is still a web or desktop game as it probably was when you were using the keyboard, you could create a GUI button and also control it through the Input manager settings,GetBbutton functions and queued animations. So basically when a button is down/pressed the 'walk animation' would play. When the button is released he stops, or the idle animation is played. If its a IOS game and you're talking about touching or tapping an on screen button its the same process but a different way to achieve it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```c#
var ball : Transform;

function Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("up"))
    {
        ball.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("down"))
    {    
        ball.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }  

    if (Input.GetKey("right"))
    {
        ball.Translate(Vector3.right* Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("left"))
    {    
        ball.Translate(Vector3.left* Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }  
}
```